# WebRTC live video stream node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, video, webrtc

I am searching for a way to stream video with webRTC. I am very new to webRTC. I have seen a lot of applications on the web that have p2p video chat. The tutorials I follow explain how WebRTC working for the client, but they do not show what use a backend script. And that's exactly what I'm looking for, a backend script (preferably node.js) that ensures that I can stream live video (getUsersMedia) to the client.

- Marnix Bouhuis

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its really simple to get started, checkout a simple demo [here](https://github.com/anoek/webrtc-group-chat-example)

1.You need a WebRTC supported browser. Chrome and firefox are best at now

2. A signalling server to exchange a media options. SocketIO with Nodejs
3. TURN and STUN server to solve NAT and Symmetric NAT (Only if you public)
4. MCU, if you want to limit the bandwidth usage. It give flexibility to a star network rather than mesh network in normal p2p

Comment: I'm sorry but how did that help with your streaming issue? > "I am searching for a way to stream video with webRTC."

Comment: @wpp i think first you need to try this step by step example [link](https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab) and check for client.html in the above answer.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your original intent. I thought you were looking for a way to do server side streaming to clients who do not support webrtc. As in A captures with webRTC B,C,D are in IE and get a "stream" from A. Sry

Comment: How to set up signalling ?

Comment: @sathishkumar_kingmaker you can check one of my demo code [here](https://github.com/svarunan/one2one-video) , I've used socket io as signalling server.
1. Register your clients to socketio (Presence will be maintained)
2. Pass all the request and response b/w browsers using socket io. since it knows the presence. Have a look at listeners in signalling.js file and video.js in the link

Comment: @SasiVarunan - Hi ! Thanks for sharing the link ... But how to set up STUN and TURN server ? is there any free public servers avaialble ?

Comment: We have plenty of open STUN servers in public [stun](https://gist.github.com/zziuni/3741933), But TURN servers are more Bandwidth dependent, Since its used to relay media. I could find only [turn](http://numb.viagenie.ca/) or amazon EC2 custom AMIs comes with ready made TURN server. Google for it!

Use fail over patterns like below

`var pc = new webkitRTCPeerConnection( {iceServers: [{url: "stun:stun.services.mozilla.com"},{url: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"}]});`